# Wireless devices are detecting DHCP/DNS but Wired are not

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, dhcp, dhcp-server, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I set up a server hosting AD, DNS, and DHCP.  My wireless devices are successfully contacting the server and receiving an IP address, but my wired devices are not connecting. I have 2 virtual servers and 1 virtual desktop using HyperV installed on the same server hosting AD, DNS, and DHCP.  These 3 devices are not able to get an ip address.  If I set a static ip address I cannot get internet connectivity either.

I am connected to the internet through an Actiontec m1424wr rev 1 Wireless Broadband Router.  I disabled DHCP on the wireless broadband router so that nothing should be handing out ip addresses except my server. Any thoughts as to what may be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: All of the devices that cannot connect virtual machines? Can the hyper-V host get DHCP/DNS/Internet? How have you set up the virtual network(s) on the Hyper-V host? It doesn't seem like a wired/wireless issue - instead it sounds more like virtual versus non-virtual.

Comment: What kind of virtual switch did you create in Hyper-V? Do the virtual machines have a virtual NIC connected to an appropriate virtual switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you probably have a misconfiguration on your Hyper-V Virtual switch. Did you create an external network virtual switch connected to your Hyper-V server NIC ? You can also check "Allow Management Operating System to share this network controller"

Walk through
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/quick_start/walkthrough_virtual_switch?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: It was a misconfiguration of the HyperV.  The External Virtual Network switch was connect to a NIC card that was not in use.  Thank you everyone for your assistance.